# How can I typeset this optimisation problem?

Tags: align, amsmath

I need to reproduce the following equation:

[image]

I've tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*} 
  \begin{aligned}
 & \text{minimize} & & \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sigma[i] (t_\text{indoor}[i] - t_\text{setpoint})^2 + \lambda \sum_{i=1}^{N}t_\text{flow}[i] && \\
 & \text{subject to} & & t_\text{indoor}[i] \geq t_\text{reduced}, && i = 1, \ldots, N \\
 & & & t_\text{indoor}[i] \leq t_\text{flow}[i] \leq t_\text{flowmax}, && i = 1, \ldots, N \\
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*} 

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't quite give what I want:

[image]

How can I make the two "i = 1, ..., N," statements remain aligned, but be closer to the constraints of this optimisation problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `align*` and `cases` environments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} & \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sigma[i] (t_\text{indoor}[i] - t_\text{setpoint})^2 + \lambda \sum_{i=1}^{N}t_\text{flow}[i] \\
\text{subject to} & \begin{cases}
                 t_\text{indoor}[i] \geq t_\text{reduced},& i = 1, \ldots, N \\
                 t_\text{indoor}[i] \leq t_\text{flow}[i] \leq t_\text{flowmax}, & i = 1, \ldots, N \\
                    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see `cases` environment produces left braces, if you dont want braces you could write

```
\begin{array}{ll}
 t_\text{indoor}[i] \geq t_\text{reduced},& i = 1, \ldots, N \\
 t_\text{indoor}[i] \leq t_\text{flow}[i] \leq t_\text{flowmax}, & i = 1, \ldots, N 
\end{array}
```

instead

```
\begin{cases}
   t_\text{indoor}[i] \geq t_\text{reduced},& i = 1, \ldots, N \\
   t_\text{indoor}[i] \leq t_\text{flow}[i] \leq  t_\text{flowmax}, & i = 1, \ldots, N \\
\end{cases}
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Good answer. If you simply use an array, (`\begin{array}{ll}`) instead of the `cases` environment, you can lose the brace as well :)

Comment: Yeah, I write `cases` because is more clear the conditions ...

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions, with `mathtools` and `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
                  & \text{minimize} & \quad & \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sigma[i] (t_\text{indoor}[i] - t_\text{setpoint})^2 + \lambda \sum_{i=1}^{N}t_\text{flow}[i] \\
                  & \text{subject to} & &
  \begin{aligned} & t_\text{indoor}[i] \geq t_\text{reduced}, & & i = 1, \ldots, N \\
                  & t_\text{indoor}[i] \leq t_\text{flow}[i] \leq t_\text{flowmax}, & & i = 1, \ldots, N \\
  \end{aligned}
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    & \text{minimize} & \quad & \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sigma[i] (t_\text{indoor}[i] - t_\text{setpoint})^2 + \lambda \sum_{i=1}^{N}t_\text{flow}[i] \\
    & \text{subject to} & &
  \begin{array}{|@{\:}l} t_\text{indoor}[i] \geq t_\text{reduced}, \\[0.5ex]
  t_\text{indoor}[i] \leq t_\text{flow}[i] \leq t_\text{flowmax},
  \end{array}\quad i = 1, \ldots, N
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]